# Installed Sun Java 6 - configuration problem when running as sudo

Tags: 10.04, java

I have install Sun Java 6 on an Ubuntu server and set an environment variable in the default profile as per the instructions at http://www.edugate.ie/workshop-guides/shibboleth-2-identity-provider-installation-linux-debian-or-ubuntu

I then try to run an installer for a Java servlet - but when I run it as myself, it cannot create the required directory in /opt. When I run it as sudo, I am told that JAVA_HOME is not correct and it doesn't even start the installer - shouldn't this be coming from /etc/profile like it is for my normal user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of running it via sudo, run it in a root shell...
sudo su
then check your environment variables and fix as necessary
echo $JAVA_HOME
then run the installer or set the variable if it needs setting

Comment: ok - how do I check and fix?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java/home
```

example:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
```

Then run your applet like below:

```
sudo env JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME your_applet_or_script
```

example:

```
sudo env JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME /usr/bin/eclipse
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Very generally speaking (and just looking *very* briefly at those instructions you linked to), you want to run tomcat as a non-root user.  This is both safer & more convenient (since you don't have to do everything as root).

But that also means tomcat will have to run on a higher port (e.g., 8080 or such). And in order to service client requests on the more common port 80, you run Apache on port 80 in front of Tomcat (which the instructions also outline), and Apache connects to tomcat via mod_jk on another port (e.g., 8009 (http) or 8443 (https) or such).

Now, in order to install Java apps in Tomcat, just chown / chmod your tomcat directory so that your "web user" (possibly your own non-root user account) can write to it.  For example,

```
 $ sudo mkdir /opt/tomcat
```

And then typically chown (or just chmod):

```
 $ sudo chown my_user:my_group /opt/tomcat
```

Now, do everything as a non-root account, and no sudo is necessary. It might still be a good idea to have a semi-restricted "web-admin" account if this is a shared server, rather than using your own login.

Comment: While this is a very good answer to some question - this isn't the answer to my question at the top...

Comment: Yes, there _two_ correct answers: login & do everything as root (the accepted answer), or set things up "correctly" (this answer). Long story short, if you install a container as "root", then you have to install and run everything inside that container as "root" (using sudo won't do). Heads will bang against walls until you surrender & just set things up "right" (from personal experience).  It's kind of like in windows, where you end up being "administrator" to do _anything_. But you don't want to end up in this situation in linux, where you login as root, stay as root, "rm -fr /" as root...